# CSS: How to enable scrolling in table tds with a constraint on two columns

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a 3-column table contained in a section that defines a constrained area (width and height).

This table needs to spread in the whole section.
The two first columns have a fixed element in the bottom that constraints their height.

I want to make everything flexible to adapt to various form factor.

The fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/stephanedeluca/Gv74f/#base

The code snippet as follows:

```
<section>
    <div style="height:calc(100% - 20px)">
        <!-- three-first consequences, cause, cure-column rows -->
        <table style="background-color:rgb(252,252,252);">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Consequences</th>
                    <th>Causes</th>
                    <th>Cures</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <!-- consequences column -->
                    <td style="border-right: solid 6px white; width:33%">
                        <div class="vScrollable" style="height: calc(100% - 100px)">
                            <ul>
                                <li>1</li>
                                <li>2</li>
                                <li>3</li>
                                <li>4</li>
                                <li>5</li>
                                <li>6</li>
                                <li>7</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <!-- causes column -->
                    <td style="border-right: solid 6px white; width:33%">
                        <div class="vScrollable" style="height: calc(100% - 100px)">
                            <ul>
                                <li>1</li>
                                <li>2</li>
                                <li>3</li>
                                <li>4</li>
                                <li>5</li>
                                <li>6</li>
                                <li>7</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>

                    <!-- cures column -->
                    <td rowspan="2">
                        <div class="vScrollable">
                            <ul>
                                <li>1</li>
                                <li>2</li>
                                <li>3</li>
                                <li>4</li>
                                <li>5</li>
                                <li>6</li>
                                <li>7</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <div style="background-color: lightblue; width: 400px; height: 100px">
                            to stay at the bottom
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I want to make everything flexible to adapt to various form factor"?

Comment: As the section spread the total surface of the device, and various devices are being used with different width x height sizes, I want the content of the section to use this space while the div being stuck to the bottom of the table @Jason